# How to keep leading zero when returning value from modulo Python

Tags: python, numbers

I want to build a program which allows the user to input a number then make that number exponent of 2. Also user inputs how many last digits of final number wants to see. This is my code:

```
  
         exponent = eval(input('Type in exponent '))
         lastDigits = eval(input('Type in how many digits you want to see'))
         number = 2**exponent
         print(number /int(('1'+('0'*lastDigits))))
```

The output for example is:
Type in exponent =  10
Type in how many digits you want to see = 3

Here comes the problem.
If my exponent is 10 that means 2**10 = 1024
I want to see 3 last digits so that is 024 but Python doesn't keep this leading zero so I just get 24. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use string operations instead of integer operations:

```
exponent = int(input('Type in exponent '))
lastDigits = int(input('Type how many digits you want to see '))
number = 2 ** exponent
cropped = str(number)[-lastDigits:]
print(cropped) # Result: "024"
```

I'm essentially just slicing off all but the last `lastDigits` characters in the string representation of `number`, that way we include any leading zeroes.

I also switched to using `int` casting instead of the `eval` function, because the `eval` function could be potentially dangerous if anyone decides to put something destructive into the input.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much.